# How perform Login request to *.aspx site from c# mobile app

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I'm trying to perform login request in C#, but i don't know how to do it. I tried to find aspx web API but with no result. Do you know something about it?

here you have url: https://www.bikes-srm.pl/Login.aspx

Everything I tried is send request witch this header:

```
webreq.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("login:password"));
```

Comment: Are you sure it's using basic authentication?

Comment: I'm not sure, it's only one thing I found in web about asp.net api

Comment: Do you own that site?

Comment: No, I don't. But I'm trying make client of that site. I think that cookies can be used too in authentication process

Comment: Use a tool such as [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to watch the traffic as you log into that site with your browser. Examine the requests and response to see how it handles authentication. Then duplicate that in your client.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing how you tagged ASP.NET and mentioned "c# mobile app," here's one potential answer to your problem. [This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/50544/Using-the-WebBrowser-Control-in-ASP-NET) covers the approach in detail, summarized below:

> You can use a WebBrowser control to login to a website, wait until the content is loaded, and then retrieve the HTML data, cookies, get/set values of input elements, and access running scripts.

However, keep in mind:

- Security: If more than one person can login, you will need to sandbox each user, clear tracking data, cookies, etc. at the end of each session and manage multiple states. If financial transactions occur through that website, you're taking risks.
- Harder to maintain: The id's / names for the form fields or URLs can change, and when they do, your program may break.
- Liability: from a legal perspective, who's responsible for what happens through your program? Do you have written permission to access their website from your program?
- WebBrowser control is a part of `System.Windows.Forms`, but it looks like you'll be using it from within an ASP.NET site or a mobile app. What are the consequences? Research this.

Comment: Using a web browser control is not a good solution when all you want to do is simply log into a site programmatically. Instead, you should figure out how it handles authentication and duplicate that.

Comment: It's not as simple as you think. The website he linked to appears to use cookie-based authentication. Unless you want to implement all that logic yourself, this is one solution. Note that I never said this was a good solution; I mentioned several negative points.